# getStringExtra() fails in onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to transfer additional data from an Intent to the calling activity.
The base activity does "startActivityForResult()".

The nested activity sets the result and puts additional data in a click-listener:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     setResult(LOGIN_RESULT_IN);
     LoginActivity.this.getIntent().putExtra("username", userStr);
     LoginActivity.this.getIntent().putExtra("password", passStr);

     LoginActivity.this.finish();
}
```

The calling activity checks the data with:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    preferences.username = data.getStringExtra("username");
    preferences.password = data.getStringExtra("password");
}
```

however this return always null. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
public void onClick(View v) {

      Intent intent=new Intent();
      intent.putExtra("username", userStr);
      intent.putExtra("password", passStr);

      setResult(LOGIN_RESULT_IN,intent);
     LoginActivity.this.finish();
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    preferences.username = data.getStringExtra("username");
    preferences.password = data.getStringExtra("password");
}
```

Comment: that's it, thanks! I don't create a new Intent object like you propose, but hand over the existing one, but doesn't really matter. I wonder why I need to explicitely set an Intent with setResult(), why doesn't it by default forward the existing one?

Comment: ok, it's not a problem use this below code without creating a new intent  LoginActivity.this.getIntent().putExtra("username", userStr);
     LoginActivity.this.getIntent().putExtra("password", passStr);
     setResult(LOGIN_RESULT_IN,this.getIntent());

     LoginActivity.this.finish();